# Print only one CURL response after redirects Powershell

Tags: powershell, http, curl, redirect, http-headers

How do I build a cURL command that will follow redirects, but only return the content from the final (200) response? For example, I run `curl.exe -LIk securityheaders.com` and it returns the 301 response headers and the 200 response headers. I want to assign a variable to that cURL and only have the regex from the 200 response headers to check against a set of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using -LIk that means:

- -k, --insecure Allow insecure server connections (OK)
- -L, --location Follow redirects (OK)
- -I, --head Show document info only (WHY)

When you put -I you are request for the document info only when all you want to is the content, just remove -I.

```
curl -Lk securityheaders.com
```

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> <html lang="en">
> ...
> ```